# Calculation with Radio Button and Check Box

Tags: vb.net

I’m a beginner programmer that is trying to get my program calculations to work with radio boxes and check boxes.

I need to keep track of the total, so if someone picks a car there is a multiplier to which car you pick. ex. BMW = 1.5 of the BasePrice of 20,000… = 30000. So if you add options like convertible, wheel performance etc. It adds with with multiplier.

I know it’s a little sloppy  and it doesn't make sense in a real world application cause a car  has this and that. It's just illustrate an example and help me with my calculations.

How do I take the my options Constants and assign it to a variable so it can calculate the price? Once I start switching through cars, I can't get it to multiply by the multiplier value. So if you got leather in a BMW its 1.5 more but if you got leather in a Chevy its just multiplied by 1.0.. Once I start switching through I can't get the options to go beyond their flat rate. I have the code for the different cars in my program, just left it out to enhance the readability. –

BMW with Sunroof and Wheels upgrade would be multiplied by 1.5
Chevy with Sunroof and Wheels upgrade would be multiplied  1.0
And when you check and uncheck and switch around options the Cost switches as well.

Appreciate any help, thank you guys.

```
Const BasePrice As Double = 20000
Public Const BMW As Double = 1.5
Public Const Chevrolet As Double = 1.0
Public Const Leather As Double = 2000
Public Const Sunroof As Double = 1000
Public Const GPS As Double = 2000
Public Const Performance As Double = 3000
Public Const Wheels As Double = 2000

Dim Sum As Double
Dim options As Double


Sub calculate()
    If optBMW.Checked Then
        Sum = BMW * (BasePrice + options)
        lblCost.Text = FormatCurrency(Sum)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub optBMW_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optBMW.CheckedChanged
    calculate()
End Sub

Private Sub chkLeather_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLeather.CheckedChanged
    If chkLeather.Checked = True Then
        Sum += Leather
        lblCost.Text = Sum
    End If

    If chkLeather.Checked = False Then
        Sum -= Leather
        lblCost.Text = Sum
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub chkWheelUpgrade_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkWheelUpgrade.CheckedChanged


End Sub
```

Picture of Interface

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9PJZ.png

Comment: VB.NET is not vba.  I removed the other erroneous tags, please fix those.  I am not sure I understand the question - cars are not priced by the pound or unit (a Merc may cost 2 times a Yugo but that is an accident of the data).  Options like air conditioning and heated seats would be more real-world.  And ***pleeeease*** do not post pictures of code - the code needs to be here in the post.  See [Ask]

Comment: Remove the vba tag since it does look like VB.NET, then ask a specific question - what doesnt work?  You should also turn on option strict and learn about datatype conversions now.

Comment: How do I take the my options Constants and assign it to a variable so it can calculate the price? Once I start switching through cars, I can't get it to multiply by the multiplier value. So if you got leather in a BMW its 1.5 more but if you got leather in a Chevy its just multiplied by 1.0.. Once I start switching through I can't get the options to go beyond their flat rate. I have the code for the different cars in my program, just left it out to enhance the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   Public BasePrice As Double = 20000
   Public BMW As Double = 1.5
   Public Chevrolet As Double = 1.0
   Public Leather As Double = 2000
   Public Sunroof As Double = 1000
   Public GPS As Double = 2000
   Public Performance As Double = 3000
   Public Wheels As Double = 2000

   Dim Sum As Double = 0
   Dim options As Double = 0


   Sub calculate()
       If optBMW.Checked Then
           Sum = BMW * (BasePrice + options)
           lblCost.Text = FormatCurrency(Sum)
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub optBMW_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optBMW.CheckedChanged
       calculate()
   End Sub

   Private Sub chkLeather_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLeather.CheckedChanged
       If chkLeather.Checked = True Then
           Sum += Leather
           lblCost.Text = Sum
       End If

       If chkLeather.Checked = False Then
           Sum -= Leather
           lblCost.Text = Sum
       End If


   End Sub
```

Comment: I need to get rid of the decimal places for my output. So its just flat $100,000; Not $100,00.00....

You can see I used "FormatCurrency" but and I started static casting my options.. But idk if it's what I should be doing?

lblTotalCost.Text = CStr(options)

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

```
Const BasePrice As Double = 20000
Public Const BMW As Double = 1.5
Public Const Chevrolet As Double = 1.0
Public Const Leather As Double = 2000
Public Const Sunroof As Double = 1000
Public Const GPS As Double = 2000
Public Const Performance As Double = 3000
Public Const Wheels As Double = 2000

Dim Sum As Double
Dim options As Double


Sub calculate()
    If optBMW.Checked Then
        Sum = BMW * (BasePrice + options)
        lblCost.Text = FormatCurrency(Sum)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub optBMW_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles optBMW.CheckedChanged
    calculate()
End Sub

Private Sub chkLeather_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLeather.CheckedChanged
    If chkLeather.Checked = True Then
        options += Leather
        lblCost.Text = options 
    End If

    If chkLeather.Checked = False Then
        options -= Leather
        lblCost.Text = options 
    End If

    calculate()

End Sub
```

as you can see. I used the variable **option** in the checkboxes instead of sum (you'll only use the **sum** after you apply the multiplier). do it in all of your checkboxes.

then call the **calculate** in all of your checkboxes and radiobuttons so it will recalculate everytime you check and uncheck.